# What causes this error on the Collins 60A ADF system?

Tags: aircraft-maintenance, avionics

We've got a BAE Jetstream 32 equipped with a dual Collins 60A ADF system, and the co-pilot's side control head is:

1. displaying "FLAG 10" when we press the TEST button; We looked up the error code, but the only information we got is that the code corresponds to "ADF not locked in ADF mode" with no rectification. This is the first error of this type we've seen.
2. would not function for the last flight crew that flew it.

We tried replacing the controller, the signal adapter and the receiver. We've been banging our heads against this for hours. Anyone seen a similar failure, and know what we've been doing wrong?

Comment: Hi 3433, welcome to Aviation!  Although I think your question is well written and on-topic, I have serious doubts that it will accumulate good answers simply because of how specific the circumstances are.  Hopefully, I'm wrong :)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about avionics equipment support, which should be directed to the manufacturer.

Comment: Since the problem didn't go away when swapping the controller or the receiver, I'd rule them out as culprits. The message indicates that it is setting ADF mode, but it isn't locked.  All of that tells me the issue is with the loop portion of the antenna or its cabling/connections.  I'd check the cable connectors and ring out the cables.  Any impedance mismatch between the loop cables could cause the issue.  If nothing shows there, then try swapping the antenna.

Comment: Very much an opportunity to contact Collins. They'd be able to get you the most accurate answer much more quickly than asking the world in general. I'd imagine that they'll also have a solution (or at least detailed trouble shooting steps) at hand.